# Solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^3 + x$ for $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a seemingly simple first order separable differential equation that I'm getting stuck on.  This is what I have so far:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^3+x$$

goes to

$$\frac{dx}{x(1+x^2)} = dt$$

Now using partial fractions to integrate the left-hand side:
$$\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{Bx+C}{1+x^2}$$

Solving for A, B, C:
$1 = A(1+x^2) + (Bx+C)x$, and using coefficient matching, I get $A=1, B=-1, C=0$.

So the integral yields: 
$$\int\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx = \int dt$$

This yields: $$\ln x -\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2) =t + C$$

So I tried using log rules and such to solve for $x$.  I think this is where my source of error is.

**My attempt:**

$$\ln x - \ln(1+x^2)^\frac{1}{2} = t+C$$
$$\ln\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} = t + C$$
$$\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}= Ce^t$$

But this seems wrong.  I apologize in advance if it's a silly mistake that I didn't see.

Comment: Probably multiplying the differential equation with $2x$ and setting $y = x^2$ is easier, although what you have looks right too. But you still have to bring that last equation into the form $x = ...$.

Comment: It does not seem wrong to me, expect for the minor correction $C\rightarrow \exp(C):=C'$ in the last equality. Make $x(t)$ explicit and you are done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that $x\ge 0$.

$$\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}= \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}$$
and you can probably take it from there.

If $x<0$, then $x=-\sqrt{x^2}$ and proceed similarly.

Answer (score 5):

You should get 
$$ C^2e^{2t}=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=1-\frac1{1+x^2},$$
hence
$$ x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-C^2e^{2t}}-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach comes by writing the ODE as
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}-x=x^3,
$$
showing that it a [Bernoulli differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation). This can be transformed to a linear ode with the substitution $u=x^{1-3}=x^{-2}$.

This substitution gives
$$
-2\frac{du}{dt}-u=1,
$$
which can be solved using regular first order techniques.